# Hide Member list from users

Tags: sharepoint-online

What I would like to find out is how I can hide this memberlist on a sharepoint folder. I would also like to hide it from showing up on the group emails.

[image: screenshot of member list]

Answer (score 0):

They display be default and there is no OOB method to disable them.

To hide the members on the top right corner, you may need scripts such as CSS or JavaScript.

In SharePoint Online modern experience, we need to use SharePoint Framework Extensions to add scripts to "modern" pages.

Check Information about [Customizing the "modern" experiences in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Another workaround, you could switch the experience from modern to classic. The members are not appeared in classic experience.